# Is is possible to put a time.sleep(n) in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.5

Is it possible to put a `time.sleep(n)` in a list comprehension to print each item in the list with a delay between each print?

```
import random, time

outside_lights = ['LED_fgate',
    'LED_rgate',
    'LED_mandoor',
    'LED_garage',
    'LED_garWin',
    'LED_rgb',
    'LED_deckOld',                 
    'LED_deckNew',
    'LED_cleartube',                  
    'LED_cleartube2'
]

random.shuffle(outside_lights, random.random)

print [i for i in outside_lights]
```

Comment: Just use `for i in outside_lights`.

Answer (score 9):

**If** condition in the list comprehension can be one option for the case.

```
import random, time

outside_lights = ['LED_fgate',
    'LED_rgate',
    'LED_mandoor',
    'LED_garage',
    'LED_garWin',
    'LED_rgb',
    'LED_deckOld',                 
    'LED_deckNew',
    'LED_cleartube',                  
    'LED_cleartube2'
]

random.shuffle(outside_lights, random.random)

print [i for i in outside_lights if time.sleep(1) is None]
```

Comment: Try editing your answer as code and do a bit more explaining, please.

Comment: Great job! The only answer that actually addressed the OP question.

Answer (score 4):

No, and the code you have there won't get what (I suspect) you want.

`print [some comprehension]` will simply produce the whole list.  I think you want each item.  To do this, you must loop over the list.  Something like:

```
for val in list:
    print val
```

Then you could:

```
for val in [your list comprehension]:
    print val
    time.sleep(n)
```

for the desired effect.

As a general rule, you cannot put [statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html) (things that do stuff like `print`, `import`, etc) within comprehensions.  These are cases where whatever you're doing with a comprehension must be done as a loop.  Many people think of comprehensions as a shorthand for loops, **but this is not correct**.  Comprehensions are only shorthand for object creation (which can also be accomplished by looping)

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in outside_lights:
    time.sleep(10)
    print i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't in python2 because print isn't a function, but you can in python3 if you don't mind creating a dummy list in the process. In python2, you can define a function for print and then do:

```
def p(x)
    print x

[(p(i), time.sleep(.2) for i in outside_lights]
```

With this, the prints happen every .2 seconds. A list of [(None, None), (None,None),...] gets created and discarded when the list completes.

The for loop examples are likely a much better choice. (the different between 'can' and 'should')

Answer (score 0):

```py
from time import sleep

lista_num = [list(range(1,4)),list(range(4,7)),list(range(7,10))]

[[print(numero) for numero in matriz if sleep(1) is None] for matriz in lista_num]
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?